# Sql Inner join query on condition when specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query:

```
SELECT Art.Id, Art.Nummer, Art.Serie, Art.EANBarcode, Art.Preis, Art.Volumen, Art.Vater, Art.Name, Art.Amazon, Kat.Name, Subkat.Name, Subsubkat.Name FROM
tbArtikel As Art 
INNER JOIN tbKategorie As Kat ON Art.FK_Kategorie_ID=Kat.Id
INNER JOIN tbSubkategorie As Subkat ON Art.FK_SubKategorie_ID=Subkat.Id
INNER JOIN tbSubsubkategorie As Subsubkat ON Art.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID=Subsubkat.Id
WHERE RIGHT(Art.Nummer,2)='.1'
```

The situation is that Art.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID can be null (developers did that setting 0 instead of null) - knows that bad habit but how it is. However i want to make if there is really 0 for Art.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID i want to take that record and for Subsubkat.Name just put empty string. Hope got my point.

**Additional question if possible(PS):**
Is there any diffrence in where condition if i do:

```
WHERE RIGHT(Art.Nummer,2)='.1'
WHERE Art.Nummer LIKE '%.1'
```

or even:

```
WHERE NOT RIGHT(Art.Nummer,2)='.1'
WHERE Art.Nummer NOT LIKE '%.1'
```

I know that like working with indexes, but i am just talking about whether in this case both will work and search exactly the same? I am using that to get specific articles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
SELECT Art.Id, Art.Nummer, Art.Serie, 
Art.EANBarcode, Art.Preis, Art.Volumen, Art.Vater, Art.Name, 
Art.Amazon, Kat.Name, Subkat.Name, ISNULL(Subsubkat.Name,'')
FROM
tbArtikel As Art 
INNER JOIN tbKategorie As Kat ON Art.FK_Kategorie_ID=Kat.Id
INNER JOIN tbSubkategorie As Subkat ON Art.FK_SubKategorie_ID=Subkat.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbSubsubkategorie As Subsubkat ON Art.FK_SubSubKategorie_ID=Subsubkat.Id
WHERE RIGHT(Art.Nummer,2)='.1'
```

Comment: And to answer your other question. There would be a difference. While the like operator will return the correct results it will also include values that contain something like '.1ABCD', '.1.111'. The RIGHT operator will ensure that you are only checking the last 2 characters.

Comment: so this means when i want to take records from column that ends with .1 this query is correct one : WHERE RIGHT(Nummer,2) = '.1'  and if not then WHERE NOT RIGHT(Nummer,2) = '.1'  am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Or else, just write WHERE RIGHT(Nummer,2) <> '.1'

Comment: why did you used LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: and like will still give me the corerct result or not (dont get at all)?

Comment: A LEFT OUTER JOIN basically means that you want to return a record even if there is no match on your join. So in your case, if the FK value has a value of '0' or NULL it will return the same number of records. There are lots of resources out there that explain the types of joins and their respective meanings. See here for example; https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php

Comment: and about LIKE - i thought it will give same results as right in this case.

Comment: HI!. Yes it will do

Comment: so what did you mean by this: something like '.1ABCD', '.1.111'. The RIGHT ?

Comment: Actually, I'll correct myself. '%.1' will yield the same results. Apologies. As there is no wildcard after the 1.